# How to Union every 2 consecutive columns from the same table

Tags: mysql

```
date1   tran_1   date2  tran_2    date3  tran_3 ..... date80  tran_80
may01   24       jun02   32       aug18    56   .....   sep10   44        
Sep01   24       Nov08   32       Jan18    56   .....   Jun18   44
```

Now the output should be and How to write a dynamic query.. I have written a procedure by passing parameters , for the above 80 variables i have to call the procedure about 40 times, plz help me

```
date    tran      type
may01   24        tran_1  
Sep01   24        tran_1
jun02   32        tran_2  
Nov08   32        tran_2       
aug18   56        tran_3 
Jan18   56        tran_3 
........................
........................
sep10  44        tran_80  
Jun18  44        tran_80
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to just use `union all`:

```
select date, tran_1 as tran, 'tran_1' as type from t union all
select date, tran_2 as tran, 'tran_2' as type from t union all
select date, tran_3 as tran, 'tran_3' as type from t union all
. . .
```

My recommendation would be to generate the code in a spreadsheet.  Just generate the numbers 1 to 80 and use spreadsheet functions.  Alternatively, you could generate dynamic SQL, if you don't want to type all the column names in.

If performance is an issue *and* you have lots and lots data, there are other methods.  However, this type of query is often run only once and a more efficient query is more difficult to construct.